# Getting "Cannot GET/" from API test in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, express, asp.net-web-api

I am new to Node.JS I am trying to compile a node with express API but without success, Tried to debug the App just stops in the first module import, I create similar app from tutorial ran well but not saving input data, code bellow:

URL:  localhost:3000/api/v1/students

Server.js

```
// Dependences 
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var express = require("express");
var mongoose = require("mongoose");



var app = express();


//connect to database

mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/rest_test");

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get("/api/v1",require("./routes/api"));



app.listen(3000,
    function(req,resp)
    {

      console.log("is Working bitch!");

    });
```

./routes/api.js

```
var express = require("express");

var router = express.Router();

var Students = require("../models/Students");

Students.methods(["get","post","put","delete"]);

Students.register(router, "/Students");

module.exports = router;
```

./models/Students.js

```
var restful = require("node-restful");

var mongoose= restful.mongoose;


var StudentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
    name : String,
    course : String

});

module.exports = restful.model("Students",StudentSchema);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved,

Instead of get must be use:

```
app.use("/api/v1",require("./routes/api"));
```